# align-items, align-self not working on IE11

Tags: html, css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I have a [simple plunker here.](https://plnkr.co/edit/MJln4elbVC1SMXJ3A3bA?p=preview)

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 4em;
}

.nav {      
  flex: 0 0 4em;
  height: 1em;
}

.logo {
  flex: 1 0 auto; 
  align-self: stretch;
}
```

This is working how I want it to in Chrome 49:

[image]

But not in IE11:

[image]

I have checked that IE isn't in compatability mode - it's not - it's in IE11 mode.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a bug in IE11.

The `min-height` property on a flex container isn't recognized by flex items in IE11.

If you switch to `height: 4em`, you'll see that your layout works.

A simple workaround is to make `.container` a flex item.

In other words, add this to your code:

```
body {
    display: flex;
}

.container {
    width: 100%; /* or flex: 1 */
}
```

For whatever reason, by making your flex container also a flex item, the `min-height` rule is respected by the child elements.

More details here: [*Flexbugs: `min-height` on a flex container won't apply to its flex items*](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-3)