# How can a flex item be made to fit the height of its parent when using IE11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

In this example below I cannot find a way using the css flex model to make div `B` fill the height of div `A`. When `flex-direction` is `column` the child div still collapses even when no heights are specified.

```css
.A {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background: #00b;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.B {
  background: #b00;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 0%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <div class="B">
    I WISH I WAS AS BIG AS MY DAD
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You'd have to make the parent `flex-direction:column`...right?

Comment: The issue here is `min-height`...I think. As I recall, IE has issues with flexbox and `min-x`.

Comment: Column doesn't fix this issue but I need the height to work when flex is row also as it does in well behaved browsers.

Comment: red div is taking over the blue div? (red is on top of blue)

Comment: @Hash not in Internet explorer

Comment: @Obsidian got it :)

Comment: You sure this isn't a duplicate? Sure looks like one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40775317/3597276

Comment: Works fine now in IE11: https://jsfiddle.net/53x83tbe/

Comment: @Michael_B revised.

Comment: Alas, the second code sample is also a dupe. The problem is IE doesn't propertly parse percentage values on `flex-basis` in the `flex` shorthand. Make it unitless (`flex: 1 1 0`) and it works fine in IE11. https://jsfiddle.net/cuosrg2j/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32239549/3597276

Comment: @Michael_B I revised my answer, though it still might be a dupe...you decide if you want to close it a such

Comment: @Obsidian Revised my answer

Comment: The OP can decide. Hopefully problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Revised answer based on a question edit.*

---

This is one of IE's many flex bugs, where it won't recognize its parents height under some circumstances.

In this case, when using flex container with column direction, if you use a *unitless* value for `flex-basis` you'll get the same result cross browsers.

```css
.A {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background: #00b;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.B {
  background: #b00;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 0;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <div class="B">
    I WISH I WAS AS BIG AS MY DAD
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If the sole purpose is to make the items fit the height of its parent, I recommend to use the longhand `flex-grow: 1` instead.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qhp77kd0/2/)

Stack snippet

```css
.A {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  background: #00b;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.B {
  background: #f66;
  -ms-flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="A">
  <div class="B">
    I AM AS BIG AS MY DAD
  </div>
</div>
```

---

*Here is also [a fiddle sample](https://jsfiddle.net/qhp77kd0/1/), showing both a row and column version.*

Comment: thanks for this however it doesn't solve the problem if no heights are set as in my second example. Any ideas?

Comment: @Obsidian Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this looks ok however I already added units into all my flex attributes because Chrome doesn't respect the values otherwise :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37386244/what-does-flex1-mean#answer-42630660

Comment: @Obsidian For the column direction it works in Chrome as well, when you use shorthand `flex` and unitless _flex-basis_ value, still, I recommend you use the longhand `flex-grow` instead.  What is the reason you want to set the `flex-basis` to 0%?

Comment: Mainly for cross browsers issues. Shorthand `Flex:1` causes all kinds of issues. When I use expanded `Flex:1 1 0` there are further issues with both IE and Chrome unless units are specified. My main problem is people won't stop using IE!

Comment: @Obsidian Then use my last sample code, which use the longhand `flex-grow`. Works cross all browsers flawless, for both row and column direction

Comment: Thanks for all your help. You have provided enough information for me to create a usable solution so thanks for your efforts where others offer none.

Comment: @Obsidian You're welcome. Btw, I also added the previous fiddle with both row and column version into my answer